# Plot multi label (values) with multi bar chart

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I've this issue I hope you can help.
I've this data :

```
to_stack = pd.DataFrame([['CHILDREN', 0.42806248287201976, 0.0],
       ['AMT_TOTAL', 165006, 179357],
       ['SAL', 582065, 703917.0],
       ['ANNUITY', 26851, 28416]], columns=('Variable','Id','Mean'))
```

When I run the code below

```
to_stack.plot.barh(x='Variable', figsize=(12,8), width = .9)

## First Loop for first Variable "ID"
for index,value in enumerate(to_stack['Id']):
    plt.text(value, index, str(value),  va='top', )

## Second Loop for Second Variable
for i,val in enumerate(to_stack['Mean']):
    plt.text(val, i, str(val),  va='bottom' )
```

I get this result [image]

The Values in each bar ar not well centralized

I've tried several options in Matplotlib.plt.text (ha (center, left, right) , va (top, bottom, baseline) without good results, sometimes it's even worse, values are one on each other.

How can we get the values aligned with the bars ?

Any ideas are really welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to extract information from the bars and annotate. That way, you have more control of how the text appears in relative to the bars:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8),)
to_stack.plot.barh(x='Variable',  width = .9, ax=ax)

for patch in ax.patches:
    w, h = patch.get_width(), patch.get_height()
    y = patch.get_y()
    
    ax.text(w + -0.1,h/2+y, f'{w:.3f}', va='center')
```

Output:

[image]